Audio Not Playing in Mobile Chrome at 100% Volume, but Works at 99%
In mobile Chrome, I'm experiencing an issue where audio does not play through headphones when the volume is set to 100%. The sound is playing but is not outputting to the headphones. However, if I lower the volume by just 1%, the sound immediately becomes audible. When I set the volume back to 100%, the audio continues to play fine. What could be causing this behavior, and is there a way to ensure the sound is always outputted at 100% volume?
I use the following code:
startProcessingFromFile(position) {
    this.inputSource = this.audioContext.createBufferSource();
    this.inputSource.buffer = this._audioBuffer;

    // Connect the source directly to the output
    this.inputSource.connect(this.audioContext.destination);

    // Calculate the offset in the audio buffer corresponding to the video position
    let sampleRate = this._audioBuffer.sampleRate;
    let startOffset = position * sampleRate;

    // Set the starting position in the audio buffer
    this.inputSource.start(0, startOffset / sampleRate);
}


P.S. I acknowledge that this could be a bug specific only to my phone with a custom ROM and root access. I'm interested to know if this issue occurs for people with regular smartphones.

Addition: If the audio is initially silent, the sound starts to appear after 5 seconds when I begin recording the screen with audio.

It generally makes more sense to edit your own post instead of commenting on it.

If you'd like us to test on our phones, please add a runnable snippet which you have tested gives you the problem you describe so we can then test it.
